# Discord.js Embedded message multiple line value

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

The standard way of sending an embedded message is:

```
message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      title: "Test:",
      fields: [
        { name: "Test 1", value="Test"},
        { name: "Test 2", value: "TEST"},
        { name: "Test 3", value: "TEST"}
      ]
    }
  });
```

I was wondering if there is any way I could make the messages in block form for example:

```
Test1:                    Test2:
test1                     test1
test2                     test2
test3                     test3
test4                     test4
```

I'm aiming so it goes inline and you can input multiple values/per title. First I thought that `\n` would do the trick but it doesn't work. I tried some other things as trying to add a embed-manager.js to it but it doesn't work aswell.

```
message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      title: "Test:",
      fields: [
        { name: "Test 1", value="Test1 \n Test2 \n Test3"},
        { name: "Test 2", value: "TEST"},
        { name: "Test 3", value: "TEST"}
      ]
    }
  });
```

I am aiming for something like this:
[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLHxA.png)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you can't use `=` on objects. It's always `:`
You can use `\n` to make a break line.
You can use `inline: true` so it shows up to 3 fields in one line.

```
message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      title: "Test:",
      fields: [
        { name: "Test 1", value: "Line1\nLine2\nLine3", inline: true},
        { name: "Test 2", value: "AlsoLine1\nAlsoLine2\nAndLine3", inline: true}
      ]
    }
  });
```

This is the result of this code:
[image: Code result]

Comment: I apologize for the post as I have missed the =. Thank you for your post.